# How to use the request key while making http request to stackexchange api Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, stackexchange-api

I have a request key but i do not know how to use it while making an http request. can someone give me an example. here is my code for the moment :

```
 function getQuestionLinks(tag) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    $http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged='+tag+ '&site=stackoverflow&filter=!BHMIbze0EPheMk572h0ktETsgnphhV')
      .then(function(links){
        resolve(links);
      })
      .catch(reject);
    });

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [Hello World example](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code), you should be able to add on

```
&key=your_api_key
```

as a URL query parameter.